# How to find the area of a region bounded by certain hyperbola-like graphs

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $R$ be the finite region in the positive quadrant bounded by $xy = 1$, $xy = 4$, $xy^2 = 1$ and $xy^2 = 5$.
>   Find the area of R. Give your answer exactly, not as a decimal
>   approximation.

I'm not quite sure how to solve this. I know that normally for this type of question we would use the Jacobian along with a substitution, but without a function, this can't be done. Is there something I'm missing or am I over thinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(See graphic below)

Here are the functions $f$ and $g$ that allow you, to use the "jacobian method".

It suffices to set :

$$\begin{cases}u&=&xy\\v&=&xy^2\end{cases} \ \iff \ \begin{cases}x&=&\frac{u^2}{v}&=:&f(u,v)\\y&=&\frac{v}{u}&=:&g(u,v)\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

where $u$ sweeps interval $[1,4]$ and $v$ sweeps $[1,5]$.

The jacobian of (1) is  $$J(u,v)=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{2u}{v}&\frac{-u^2}{v^2}\\\frac{-v}{u^2}&\frac{1}{u}\end{vmatrix}=\frac{1}{v}$$

It suffices now to integrate

> > $$\int_{u=1}^{u=4}\int_{v=1}^{v=5}J(u,v)dudv=3 \ln(5)\approx 4.83$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I would first find the intersections among these curves. Since we are in the first quadrant, we can write

$$\gamma_1 : y = \frac1{x}$$
$$\gamma_2 : y = \frac4{x}$$
$$\gamma_3 : y = \sqrt{\frac1{x}}$$
$$\gamma_4 : y = \sqrt{\frac5{x}}.$$

The intersection between $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_3$ is $A(1,1)$. The intersection between $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_4$ is $B\left(\frac15,5\right)$. The intersection between $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ is $C\left(16,\frac14\right)$. Finally, the intersection between $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_4$ is $D\left(\frac{16}5,\frac54\right)$.

The area can then be computed as

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal A &=&\int_{\frac15}^1 \left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{x}}-\frac1{x}\right) dx +\\
& & + \int_1^{\frac{16}5}\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{x}}-\sqrt{\frac1{x}}\right) dx+\\
& & + \int_{\frac{16}5}^{16}\left(\frac4{x}-\sqrt{\frac1{x}}\right)dx
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Have a look to my solution.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes! I already have. Thanks. I haven't seen this strategy before. It's really faster in many situations like that of OP!

Comment: I haven't check if our results coincide. They should...